# How to get double tap on navigation bar

Tags: android

I'm new in android.
I'd like get double tap on navigation bar anywhere on system as home, ....
I'd want to lock device on double tap on navigation bar.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for apps receiving touch events on the navigation bar, with the exception of finding out when the user single-tapped the BACK button.

Comment: Hi @commonsware, I seen this app on xda [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/4-3-easy-lock-double-tap-status-bar-nav-t3222024) and I'd like reproduce it.